# URL processing in erlang

Tags: url, erlang

Is there a ready-to-use erlang library for processing URLs with following functionality:

- Extraction of scheme, domain, path, and file parts from the URL
- Path concatenation
- Resolving `.` and `..` path elements

More lightweight ones are more preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the [uri](https://github.com/erlware/uri/blob/master/src/uri.erl) package by Erlware

Answer (score 2):

Mochiweb includes an URL parser in the module [mochiweb_util](https://github.com/bipthelin/mochiweb_util/blob/master/src/mochiweb_util.erl).

Minimal code example:

```
{"http", "host:port", "/foo", "", "bar?baz"} =
    mochiweb_util:urlsplit("http://host:port/foo#bar?baz").
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://github.com/stfairy/eurl/blob/master/eurl.erl

I just wrote it for this question. Will add tests later on.

btw, I don't quite understand what is *path concatenation* :-)